# async processing with multiple http.post requests in angular6

Tags: http, asynchronous, angular6

I am in the process of writing a program that tracks family details. The database behind it has multiple tables (family, individual, contact numbers, dates, and emails). I have created a form that displays all of the family details from all of the tables and I want to have one save button. When the user clicks the save button, the program will check each level of data to see if anything changed and if so, it will send an http.post to update that piece of data on the server. For example, if a family has four individuals and the user changes one phone number on one of the individuals, I only want to update that one phone number so it would be an http.post to the contact numbers and nothing else. There would not be http.posts for the individual or the family.

My problem is that I need to be sure all of the http.posts complete before returning control. Normally on a single http.post, I would do a subscribe so I know when it completes. However, in this case, there could be 0 (if nothing changed) to many http.posts executed from a single button click. Since I can't nest the subscribes as in http.post(family).subscribe(http.post(individual)).subscribe(http.post...))) (ignore the syntax, this is shown for explanation only) because there may not be a change to the family and therefore the individual post would never execute.

What is the best way to handle a situation like this (other than adding a ton of "save" buttons which is not acceptable)? If you can even point me in a direction, I should be able to do the research to get it implemented.

Comment: could you send all data and let the server do the check? otherwise why do you need to wait for previous post op finish?

Comment: To do that would mean rewriting the server side and then rewriting the current client side (I didn’t mention this was being written in addition to an existing windows client).  After the save, the list of families is redisplayed and I have had times that the list of families was pulled before the update completed and I got old data in the list of families.

Comment: ok but what is the utility of wait for response? I mean in the example of sequential post request that you wrote you are not using updated families, so why to wait? Am i misunderstaing?

Comment: After the user click save, they are returned to the list of families.  If they change a family and the list beats the update, the list shows the old data.

Comment: I found the answer to be a “forkJoin”.  It allows parallel execution of http requests and does not return until they all complete.